# L8 - Sanctum - Add my own token with migration

Tags: laravel, token, laravel-sanctum

I’m using Laravel 8 with Sanctum.

Is there a way to create a migration, or what is the best practice, to add some default token every time I redeploy my project?

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, everytime your project gets deployed, your database gets migrated again, deleting old tables? And what token should be added, do you mean a `Personal Access Token` from Sanctum? If your DB gets reset on deployment, you could simply create a [seeder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding) for a `Personal Access Token` attached to your user? If not, why do you need to add a default token if the token still exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use User factory for this:

```
public function configure()
{
    return $this->afterCreating(function (User $user) {
        //You need to use some condition in user to determine, make token or not 
        if($user->isAdmin){
            $user->tokens()->create([
                'name' => 'default_token',
                'token' => 'default_token_value',
                'abilities' => '*',
            ]);
        }
    });
}
```

If user is admin - after creating - factory make default token for them.

Than, you can use factory in your seeder/tests/etc.